# Conditional Formatting based on values in a Table gives 'name range' error

Tags: excel, excel-formula, range, conditional-formatting, and-operator

I'm trying to make Excel apply Conditional Formatting to a Table based on this formula:

```
=AND([Name1]="Prawn", ISBLANK([Name4]))
```

Essentially, if the word `Prawn` is in column Name1 and the same-row cell in column Name4 is blank, Excel should apply highlighting.

The formula evaluates to a True or False state normally when tested in a cell, but when I input it in Conditional Formatting, Excel throws up an error about name ranges. I read that using the `AND` operator in conditional formatting might cause issues, but not sure how to fix it in this situation.

Comment: What is the address used for the CF rule's *Applies to:* and what is the address used for the *Refers to:* of Name1 and Name4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please select your table (assumed to be Table1) and try:

```
=AND(INDIRECT("Table1[@Name1]")="Prawn",ISBLANK(INDIRECT("Table1[@Name4]")))
```

The issue is not with the use of the `AND` operator but with the use of Tables.

Comment: Brilliant answer, but isn't it basically a workaround for some inconsistent behaviour in Excel?